# How can i disable editable text after dragging task element in bpmnJS

Tags: bpmn, bpmn.io

I have code for disabling double click event which preventing to show text field.

```
var priority = 10000;

function DisableContentEditable(eventBus) {

    eventBus.on('element.dblclick', priority, function (context) {
        var element = context.element;
        if(element.type == 'bpmn:Task' || element.type == "bpmn:StartEvent" || element.type == "bpmn:IntermediateThrowEvent" || element.type == "bpmn:EndEvent" || element.type == "bpmn:ExclusiveGateway" || element.type == "bpmn:DataObjectReference" || element.type == "bpmn:DataStoreReference"){
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

but while dragging task `element.dblclick` event is not applied and its editable. but after dragging and clicking anywhere in canvas the `element.dblclick` event is applied. but i want to disable after dragging as well.

if have any solution will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to disable `Label Editing` for BPMN.io

You have to disable `labelEditingProvider` for your modeler

```
const modelerInstance = new BpmnModeler({
  container: canvas,
  additionalModules: [{
    __init__: [
      "labelEditingProvider"
    ],
    labelEditingProvider: ['value', null],
  }],
  
});
```